# Executing a module stored as string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I am calling string and random function to make a password generator. I want to make sure that it is as random as possible but for that I think I need to call  **__all__** from **string** function, then randomly choose a possible value from the list and then execute it.

I am using exec command to execute one random string from **__any__** but I guess exec does not work on functions as it is returning None. Any solution to this or an alternative view to approach the problem might be helpful.

```
import random
from  string import *
from string import __all__
while True: #Loop can be ignored, it's just for giving user choice to quit or not. Will add options later
    required_length = input("Enter the length of the password : ") #Length of the password is stored
    letter = __all__ #List containing all the values of string. 
    password = '' #String which will store password
    counter = 1
    while  counter <= int(required_length):
        password = password + str(exec(random.choice(letter))) #Problematic part, the exec statment return None 
        counter += 1
    print (password)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to generate the password from all the string characters.

```
import random
from  string import *
from string import __all__
while True: #Loop can be ignored, it's just for giving user choice to quit or not. Will add options later
    required_length = input("Enter the length of the password : ") #Length of the password is stored
    letter = "".join([eval(i) for i in __all__ if not callable(eval(i))]) #List containing all the values of string. 
    password = '' #String which will store password
    counter = 1
    while  counter <= int(required_length):
        password = password + str(random.choice(letter)) #Problematic part, the exec statment return None 
        counter += 1
    print (password)
```

**Note:** There is a problem with the whitespace characters which should not be the part of the password. So you have to blacklist that part.